# switch between vbo binded to one vao

Tags: opengl, vbo, vao

Currently in my render function i use a VAO (Vertex Array Object) and four VBO (Vertex Buffer Object) binded with this VAO.

for each VBO, I bind to the vao

```
glGenVertexArrays (1, & vaoID [0]); // Create our Vertex Array Object
glBindVertexArray (vaoID [0]); // Bind our Vertex Array Object so we can use it

int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i <4, ++i)
{
glGenBuffers (1,vboID [i]); // Generate Vertex Buffer Object
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID [i]); // Bind Vertex Buffer Object
glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 18 * sizeof (GLfloat) vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer ((GLuint) 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  }

glEnableVertexAttribArray (0); // Disable Vertex Array Object
glBindVertexArray (0); // Disable Vertex Buffer Object
```

Then in my render function (pseudocode), for each frame:

```
glBindVertexArray (vaoID [0]);

// here, I need to draw the four VBO, but only draws the first

glBindVertexArray (0);
```

I know I can put all the geometry in a single VBO, but there are cases where its size exceeds 5Mb and this cause (possibly) that it is not placed on the GPU.

How I can switch all the binded VBO to draw them?

Answer (score 1):

3 points:

1. you can gen all buffers at once outside the loop:

   ```
   glGenBuffers (4,&vboID[0]);
   ```
2. you don't initialize the data in the vbos (that I can see)
3. you will need to loop over the vbos again and set the `glVertexAttribPointer`:

   ```
   glBindVertexArray (vaoID [0]);
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
       glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID [i]);
       glVertexAttribPointer ((GLuint) 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
       //drawArrays
   }
   glBindVertexArray (0);
   ```

Comment: thanks "ratchet freak", now I ask,  Why would the VAO is used? , if i should bind each vbo again in the render function for each frame? Otherwise,  you can  give me an example of how it would render several vbo's linked to a single vao?, Thank you!